# Moving Gutenberg content from one website to another (block media ids wrong?)

Tags: posts, block-editor

I have been looking at moving page content created in Gutenberg from one website to another.

I can use the “Copy All Content” option in the Gutenberg top right menu and if I paste this into a page on my new website all the blocks appear and seems fine.

However if I view the code behind the blocks I find that the blocks reference the IDs of the media set on the old website.

The media does not exist on the new website – what repercussions does having an incorrect media ID have here? Is there anyway other than manually downloading and reuploading the images to have these linked correctly?

If I use the WordPress export/import tool I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious result of an incorrect media ID is that it cannot find the image (because it's not in the media set).

One way to work around this, is to set up your images on the old site as url's instead of media items. I'm sure this is not the only and definitely not the best solution. However, it works for me. (Select "Insert from URL" instead of "Media Gallery". The url's for each image are shown in the "Copy Link" field when you select the image in the media gallery). However, this means that the image have to remain available on the old website.